# sinon spying on callbacks

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, sinon

I feel like I generally understand how sinon works, but I'm having some trouble spying on a callback that gets passed to the imported function I'm testing.  Here's an example:

```js
import sinon from 'sinon'

const callbackCaller = (cb: (msg:string) => void, msg: string) => {
    cb(`CallbackCaller called with ${cb}, ${msg}`)
}

describe('This seems wrong', () => {
    it('should pass but doesn\'t', () => {
        const callback = (msg: string) => {
            console.log(`Callback called with ${msg}`)
        }

        const callbackSpy = sinon.spy(callback)

        callbackCaller(callback, 'tarfu')
        sinon.assert.called(callbackSpy)
    })
})
```

When run, this test is printing as expected, but the assertion fails:

```sh
$ yarn test:failure

yarn run v1.21.1
$ jest src/test.test.ts
 FAIL  src/test.test.ts
  This seems wrong
    ✕ should pass but doesn't (8ms)

  ● This seems wrong › should pass but doesn't

    AssertError: expected callback to have been called at least once but was never called

      14 | 
      15 |         callbackCaller(callback, 'tarfu')
    > 16 |         sinon.assert.called(callbackSpy)
         |                      ^
      17 |     })
      18 | })
      19 | 

      at Object.fail (../../../node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:107:21)
      at failAssertion (../../../node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:66:16)
      at Object.assert.(anonymous function) [as called] (../../../node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:92:13)
      at Object.it (test.test.ts:16:22)

  console.log src/test.test.ts:10
    Callback called with CallbackCaller called with (msg) => {
                console.log(`Callback called with ${msg}`);
            }, tarfu

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.815s, estimated 1s
Ran all test suites matching /src\/test.test.ts/i.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Note that the callback is indeed being called, as demonstrated by it printing just below the stacktrace.  I'm using node version 10.16 and jest 25.1.0.  Since the callback is logging after the failure, it kind of looks like jest is checking the spy before `callbackCaller` calls `cb` but there's no async stuff so I'm a bit at a loss.  Hoping the solution isn't "sinon doesn't do this use some other tool" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `callbackSpy` to `callbackCaller` function rather than the original `callback`. Because `sinon` wraps `callback` with a spy(`callbacksSpy`) so that you can use `sinon.assert.called` to assert it.

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import sinon from 'sinon';

const callbackCaller = (cb: (msg: string) => void, msg: string) => {
  cb(`CallbackCaller called with ${cb}, ${msg}`);
};

describe('This seems wrong', () => {
  it("should pass but doesn't", () => {
    const callback = (msg: string) => {
      console.log(`Callback called with ${msg}`);
    };

    const callbackSpy = sinon.spy(callback);

    callbackCaller(callbackSpy, 'tarfu');
    sinon.assert.called(callbackSpy);
  });
});
```

Unit test results:

```sh
This seems wrong
Callback called with CallbackCaller called with callback, tarfu
    ✓ should pass but doesn't


  1 passing (6ms)
```